# Java LocalDateTime formatting issue

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, formatter

I've made a class called `Observation` with a constructor which takes a single line of a CSV file as an input.  I have the `LocalDateTime` extracted, however, it's not being formatted how I intended.

```
public class Observation {

    private String date, time, datetimeStr;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    private static DateTimeFormatter FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm"); 

    public Observation(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.trim().split(",");
        if (parts.length != 14) {
            throw new InputMismatchException("Error: Invalid data!");
        }

        date = String.valueOf(parts[6]);
        time = String.valueOf(parts[7]);
        dateTimeStr = date + " " + time;
        dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, FORMAT);
    }

    // DateTime Getter
    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
      return dateTime;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input= "Leeds,Albion Street North,2017,March,13,Saturday,01-Apr-17,00:00,197,0,197,197,0,197";

        Observation test = new Observation(input);

        // Print out DateTime
        System.out.println("Date-Time: " + test.getDateTime());

    }
}
```

So the format I want it to be is `"01-Apr-17 00:00"` and I'm using the formatter `"dd-MMM-yy HH:mm"` as specified above.

And the result I'm getting from terminal, when using the dateTime getter is:

```
Ashs-MacBook-Pro:resit asheastham$ Java ObservationTest
Date-Time: 2017-04-01T00:00
```

Comment: where do you use `FORMAT` to format Date to String ?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. There's no need for you to deal with lots of different values here, and it makes it much harder to tell which part you're expecting to work differently.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: In `dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, FORMAT);`

Comment: @JonSkeet Hello, yes sorry I just wanted to outline my problem.  But it's where Jon is referring to.

Comment: So get rid of the rest, and provide this as a [mcve] we can copy/paste/compile/run with no distractions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Done, sorry about that.

Comment: No, we still can't copy/paste/compile/run. Where's the class declaration? Where's the main method? Why haven't you hard-coded the data? Why split the input instead of just using the right bit of input to start with?

Comment: @JonSkeet Apologies again.  It's my first time using stack overflow properly.  The code should now be usable.

Comment: You're never using your formatter to **format** the LocalDateTime. Only to **parse** the text.

Comment: You're *still* passing in the complete string with irrelevant data though. Why? Why not just include the text you're parsing? (And why bother with a constructor and a field? Just parse in the main method. Really focus on making this minimal - it should be about 10 lines, including imports.) But basically, as others have said, you're *parsing* correctly, but then you're just implicitly calling `LocalDateTime.toString()` without specifying a format.

Comment: (If you want me to edit your question again to show you what I was looking for, I can do so, but I'd have thought my previous comments were fairly clear.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm doing it in this way as my actual project is using two files one called Observation.java and one called ObservationTest.java, Observation.java containing a constructor which represents one line of a csv file and getters for each variable.  And then an ObservationTest which takes "dummy" input, creates a new observation object and displays the different variables.  But yes, it would be a great help if you would like to reformat my post.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry I'm still very new to java and I'm trying to put it in a way which helps you understand my whole task.

Comment: But do you have any evidence that that's relevant to the question? Is your question about constructors and getters, or is it about `LocalDateTime` parsing and formatting? The point of a [mcve] is for it to be about *nothing* other than the problem at hand. Your current code is 34 lines, without any imports. I've just put together an example which is 11 lines *including* imports and a blank line. Don't you think that's clearer?

Comment: I appreciate that context is sometimes relevant, but you can state that briefly before the code without it being part of the example code itself. Sure, say that you're parsing a CSV file - but then show the code that's *doing* the parsing without the extraneous data. I note that although you've given us the context for the *parsing*, you haven't given the context for the *formatting*, which is the bit that's actually causing the problem here. (My guess is that in your real code you're not just printing it to the console - so what are you doing with it?)

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay that's fair, it probably isn't relevant to my question, but I didn't know whether other areas of my code were affecting the output.  And yes 11 lines including imports is obviously much clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet In my real code, I'm doing System.out.println("Date-Time: " + test.getDateTime());

Comment: @JonSkeet How would I go about formatting the output to the desired output: "01-Apr-17 00:00"?

Comment: You'd use `FORMATTER.format`...

Comment: @JonSkeet Just to clarify.  Where would I use FORMATTER.format...

Comment: Um, wherever you want to format the value... (Read the docs for detail...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making confusion between 2 different "concepts" when it comes to dates: the **value** of the date object, and the **representation** of this value in some specific format.

A `LocalDateTime` object represents a date/time: it keeps the **values** of day, month, year, hour, minute, second and nanosecond. But the date itself [has no format at all](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) - this link is about `java.util.Date`, but the general concept that a date has no format also applies to `LocalDateTime` as well.

The `LocalDateTime` object has only the values that corresponds to a date and time, but those values can be displayed in many different ways. And those different ways are not related to the values themselves. So, the date/time **April 1<sup>st</sup> 2017 at midnight** can be represented/displayed in many different **formats**:

- April 1<sup>st</sup> 2017 00:00:00
- 01/04/2017 0:00
- 01-Apr-17 00:00
- 2017-04-01T00:00
- and many others...

Although all the **formats** above are different, **they represent the same date and time**. The **values** of the respective fields (day, month, year, hour, second, etc) are the same, thus all represent the same date/time value (in this case, the same `LocalDateTime`).

---

When you do `LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, FORMAT)`, you are converting a specific **format** to a date value (in this case, to a `LocalDateTime`). This operation is called **parsing**: get a `String` (a text) in a specific **format** and convert it to date/time **values**.

The `DateTimeFormatter` created specifies what's the format:

```
FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm")
```

This means that the `String` to be parsed will be in the format specified - in this case, `dd` (day with 2 digits), followed by `-`, followed by `MMM` (month short name) and so on. The [**javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) contains detailed information about all available patterns.

---

When you do:

```
System.out.println("Date-Time: " + test.getDateTime());
```

This code implicity calls `toString()` method of `LocalDateTime`, and this method [returns the date/time in a specific format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--):

> Outputs this date-time as a String, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.
>   The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
>   uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
>   uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
>   uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
>   uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero

That's why your program outputs the date as `2017-04-01T00:00`: that's the result of `LocalDateTime::toString()` method.

---

If you want to print the `LocalDateTime` in the format `01-Apr-17 00:00`, you should call `FORMAT.format(test.getDateTime())` (as already explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45535298/7605325)).

If you need both the `LocalDateTime` (to store it, [as you said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534893/java-localdatetime-formatting-issue#comment78030967_45535298)) and the date in the specified format, and do everything in the constructor, you must keep 2 different fields (one `LocalDateTime` and one `String`).

Actually, you're already doing it. Your `dateTimeStr` field already contains the date in the desired format, so just create a getter for it. Or create another method (like `getFormattedDateTime()`) that returns `FORMAT.format(this.dateTime)`. Then you'll have 2 methods: one that returns the `LocalDateTime` (when you need the date object, like when storing it), and another that returns the formatted `String` (when you need to print it).

---

One more thing: the month name ("Apr") is in English. Your code is working because the JVM's default locale in also English, but it's not guaranteed that it'll always be like that. And the default locale can be changed without notice, even at runtime (some other application in the same JVM can call `Locale.setDefault()`, or someone can misconfigure the JVM and your code will suddenly break).

To avoid this, you can set the formatter with a `java.util.Locale` and make it explicit that you're using English:

```
// formatter always uses English for month names
DateTimeFormatter FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, it has helped my understanding with this topic.

Comment: I'm having a problem. I'm using your `FORMAT`, but I only get the raw numbers – no dashes or spaces or colons between the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary, to your assumption `LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr, FORMAT) does not parse _and format_ the contents of`dateTimeStr` but only parses the date-time value expecting it to have the format you specified in FORMAT.

Formatting the date-time value needs to be done when you output it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input= "Leeds,Albion Street North,2017,March,13,Saturday,01-Apr-17,00:00,197,0,197,197,0,197";

  Observation test = new Observation(input);

  // Print out DateTime
  System.out.println("Date-Time: " + FORMAT.format(test.getDateTime()));

}
```

This generates the desired output:

```
Date-Time: 01-Apr-17 00:00
```

Comment: Ash Eastham (copied from deleted answer): Okay, for my assignment, I'm not actually printing out per se, is there a way to format in my constructor?  -- My answer: You could modify `getDateTime()` to return a string and invoke format there. If you want to format in the constructor you need to store the datetime-value as a `String` instead of a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @ChristophBöhme Okay, that's makes sense to me, however I'm expected to store dateTime as a LocalDateTime

Comment: @AshEastham: Then why are you concerned about the formatting at this point? You're already parsing to LocalDateTime. When you want to format that, wherever you want to do the formatting, just use the format method on DateTimeFormatter...